# How to reuse UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

You can assume my cell is complicated enough, In order to reduce the coupling, I want implement the cell by child MVC, my sample code like this:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        CellViewController *cellVC = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellViewController" owner:self options:nil].lastObject;
        [self addChildViewController:cellVC];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellVC.view];
        cellVC.view.frame = cell.bounds;
    }

    return cell;
```

my `cellViewController` has a function `- updateUIWithModel:`

now, my question is:
1) using MVC like this is right?
2) if right, how can i set the data to cellVC?

Comment: _using MVC like this is right?_ - no. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is no need to use a child view controller.  If you want you can pass an instance of your data model to the cell and have it work with that, but the view controller lifecycle won't help you here.  It will just get in the way.

Comment: **You can assume my cell is complicated enough, In order to reduce the coupling, I want implement the cell by child MVC**

Comment: @Paulw11 My cell has many input operations, network operations and status. so if I can use child vc, it will be easy more.

Comment: Your cell **shouldn't have network operations or anything else complex**.  It should be a lightweight view onto your data.  Your model should handle all of the heavy lifting.  I'm not going to say that you *can't* make a tableview cell into a view controller, but it is going to be very difficult.  If you were to do it, you would need to do the containerisation in the cell class, not your view controller class since the cell class is where you find out about pending reuse (via `prepareForReuse`).

Comment: The network operation is not like you say. such as, my cell has any textfields and a commit button, when i press the button, i will post the content of textfields to server, so now i must implement the commit operation at current view controller, if i can use child view controller, i can implements the operation at the child, so that is my target. you know when reuse cell, the input must save so this will make my vc 
more massive.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to put a mini MVC in each cell. See for instance this article on how to add a VC to a `UITableViewCell`: http://khanlou.com/2015/04/view-controllers-in-cells/

Comment: No, your architecture is still wrong.  When you press the commit button then you should notify your model and it can submit an `NSOperation` to update the server.  Cells are ephemeral.  What happens when the user scrolls the tableview while your network operation is still in progress and the cell is reused?  There is a big difference between *can* and *should*.  Look at all of the work that person had to do in the linked blog post, when all they needed to do to put a collection view in the cell was to set the cell as the datasource and delegate.  No need for a full VC

Answer (score 0):

You need to add UITableViewDataSource，and use an NSMutableArray to set the data to cellVC.